# Does ArcGIS or ESRI's Story Maps provide interactive functions such as highlight or creating point data when a point is selected?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, story-map

I'm trying to do some spatial analysis for crime trends. I'd like to, ideally, be able to select an point (an offense) and have it then create/show specific attached points. Such as selecting a violent crime offense and then showing the offender's last known home address.

Is this possible with ESRI's story maps? I can't figure it out in just ArcGIS alone.

Alternatively, if that is not possible would it be possible to select a point and then have specific related points highlighted?

I haven't played around with interactivity before with GIS and am hoping some of this is doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As such according to my experience, there is no story map template that will let you do so by default.

You will need customization and for customizing knowledge of JavaScript is a must.

For implementing your requirements you will need to download the story map and host it on your own server, once you download the story map then you can edit the on click event and then fire the query to find the related records. Once we have the result of the query you can add the results as a graphic on the map.

Comment: Damn, I was hoping for some native way to do it as I don't know JavaScript. It can be something to look at in the future for other situations. Thank you.